# Creating Appium test run in TestDroid Cloud

Tags: android, appium, testdroid

I am trying to create an Appium test run for an Android native app in TestDroid Cloud.
When I create the project, as an Appium Android project, after I upload the app, the other options for the test run are not available [image: Options for test run not available]

From the tutorials, and from other (non-appium) projects, I see that the testrun options are available, like so:

[image: Testrun available for android only project]

So how can I upload my .zip Appium test scripts to TestDroid Cloud, and why are not the options there?
I am using a free TestDroid Cloud account, which states to support manual and automated testing of some available devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using client-side Appium where only app is uploaded to cloud and test script is executed from the localhost. The [difference of client and server-side Appium](http://testdroid.com/news/a-new-way-to-use-appiumselenium-with-real-devices-on-cloud) is from where you run your test (localhost or on cloud). With server-side Appium you can upload both app and tests on cloud and select devices you want for test run.

First thing after uploading an app to cloud is to [configure your desired capabilities](http://docs.testdroid.com/appium/testdroid-desired-caps/). Then start your test and fetch results back when all devices are finished.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, one more thing I noticed about the docs - When searching for the documentation on how to run Appium with Java, this is what I get: http://docs.testdroid.com/appium/examples/java/server-side-appium-in-tc
The docs are missing there.
Also when setting the desired capabilities from the link you provided, the capability "deviceName" is not stated as mandatory, although it is mandatory for running the tests against testdroid cloud and not mandatory when I run them locally on my device.
I hope that is useful :)